# Consume build artifact in the build pipeline itself (CI)

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, azure-artifacts, build-pipeline

is there a way that we can Consume build artifact that is generated in the CI pipeline in the subsequent task of CI pipeline **( I want to refer the artifact path in the Azure File Copy task AND in the PowerShell task).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the path to publish from your publish artifacts task. The artifacts of the pipeline are generated from the files in this folder.

[image]

You can also add a Download build artifacts task in your pipeline. Then, refer the destination directory in the subsequent tasks.

[image]